# Questions as to the preposition on

Tags: support

How to find out what questions have been asked concerning the prepositon on?
Clicking on the tag preposition does not give any results.

Comment: Here is another link to questions with the prepositions "on" and "in" http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprepositions%5D+is%3Aquestion+%22on%22+%22in%22 (DO NOT place a space after the colon **:** )

Comment: click on Preposition tag, in the search box write **is:question** and put in inverted commas the preposition you are interested in. Example **[prepositions] is:question "on"** http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bprepositions%5d%20is%3aquestion%20%22on%22 This yields 433 results.

Comment: It might be worth noting that on (in?!) *your own question* regarding this particular preposition ([**early on, later on - How to explain “on”?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/)), you didn't actually include the "preposition" tag anyway. If you don't bother tagging your own questions thoroughly, what makes you think anyone else will?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - to me, this is a common problem, and where tag edits come in. Had I seen this, I would have done a tag edit. We won't see them all, but better late than never.

Comment: @medica: I hardly ever use the built-in ELU search facilities because of the serious limitations imposed by the fact that they don't index "noise" words like ***on***. Google's "site-specific search" facilities work much better for me, but of course they don't know anything about tags. Probably mainly because of that, I don't bother much about tags myself (but I certainly wouldn't want to dissuade anyone else from "housekeeping" them).

Answer (score 3):

Click on the *preposition* tag, in the search box write

> is:question

DO NOT leave a space after the colon, and put in inverted commas the preposition you are interested in. For example

> [prepositions] is:question "on" "in"

This yielded [299 results](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprepositions%5D%20is:question%20%22on%22%20%22in%22). Adding *at* narrowed it down to a total of [66 results](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprepositions%5D%20is:question%20%22on%22%20%22in%22%20%22at%22). Without the inverted commas/speech marks the results are zero.

Comment: I didn't know this. It will make searching for dupes easier. Thanks.